# Postgres: "ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set" in recursive function

Tags: postgresql

I'm very, very new to writing Postgres functions. I'm writing a function to build a materialized path for a child by searching for parents recursively starting with the child's id. Here's the function I have, but I keep getting the error `ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set`

```
create or replace function build_mp(child_id text)
returns SETOF text 
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    select parentid from account where childid = child_id;
    if parentid IS NULL then
        return ARRAY[child_id];
    else
        return build_mp(parentid) || ARRAY[child_id];
    end if;
end $$;

SELECT build_mp('mychild');
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Edit

Here's the working solution. It takes a child's id, then searches recursively for all parents above it building a material path for the new child item.

```
create or replace function build_mp(child_id text)
returns text[] 
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    parent text;
begin
    execute 'select parentid from account where childid = $1' INTO parent USING child_id;
    if parent IS NULL THEN
        return ARRAY[child_id];
    else
        return build_mp(parent) || ARRAY[child_id];
    end if;
end $$;

SELECT build_mp('mychild') AS mp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return an array of `text`, you have to declare the function as

```
... RETURNS text[]
```

instead of

```
... RETURNS SETOF text
```

A set returning function returns a table, while an array is a single value of type `text[]`. In a set returning function, you would use `RETURN NEXT child_id` for every row you return and `RETURN` (without an argument) to terminate function processing.

PostgreSQL complains that you use `RETURN value` within a set returning function, which is not allowed.

Comment: That fixed the function. Thanks! Now however, I'm getting the error from my select at the end that says `Error: ERROR: query has no destination for result data.` What is the problem there?

Comment: Nevermind. I figured out it. I'm updating the question to show the final working solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To overcome the "*ERROR: query has no destination for result data*" error you don't need dynamic SQL.

You can [select into a variable directly](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW):

```
select parentid into parent from account where childid = child_id;
```

---

But you can simplify your function by using a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) and a SQL function. That will perform a lot better especially with a large number of levels:

```
create or replace function build_mp(child_id text)
  returns text[]
language sql
as 
$$
   with recursive all_levels (childid, parentid, level) as (
      select childid, parentid, 1
      from account
      where childid = child_id
      union all
      select c.childid, c.parentid, p.level + 1
      from account c
       join all_levels p on p.parentid = c.childid
   )
   select array_agg(childid order by level)
   from all_levels;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at the recursive CTE. Wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Your function gives the following error: `return type mismatch in function declared to return text[]`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: should work if `childid` is defined as `text`

Comment: Ah, childid is actually varchar, so had to change that line to `select array_agg(text(childid) order by level)...`

Comment: @LoneWolfPR: you should change the return type `varchar[]` instead.